# Uses of the Lax-Milgram theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

i want to prove that the function A:$H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\cap H^{2}(\Omega)\to L^{2}(\Omega)$,
with
$Au=-\Delta u  ,x\in  \Omega$ and u$=0$,$x\in \partial\Omega$(1)

i want to prove that A is bijection ,and the hint was to use Lax Milgram theorem so first i write the variational formula:
find u $\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ such that $\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \nabla v =\int_{\Omega}fv$,$\forall v \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$(2)

1. how can i prove that 1 and 2 are equivalent i prove that 1 imply 2 but can you give me a hint to show that 2 imply 1?
2. i have proved the hypothesis of lax Milgram theorem and i conclude that there is unique $u \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$  solution of 2 so its also a solution of 1  but it might be not unique for 1? and to show that u is in $H^{2}(\Omega)$ i can use elleptic regularity theorem?
   here $\Omega$ is bounded smooth domain of $R^{n}$

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's like you say. Apply Lax-Milgram. Then, $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ according to elliptic regularity and $u$ is unique ($\implies$ injectivity). In the weak formulation, you can then apply Green's theorem to get for every $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$:
$$
-\int_\Omega v(\Delta u +f) = 0.
$$
The fundamental lemma of calculus of variation implies $\Delta u+f  =0$ a.e, which is what you wanted to show.